# Copying files from a CD to hard drive, then run Java

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to have a bat inside the CD that will copy the Folder 'src' to desktop.

How can I get the files to copy to a directory, like the desktop, and then run the Java command?

```
xcopy /s/e /y c:\Desktop\Game \src

cd c:\Desktop\Game

java com/brackeen/javagamebook/tilegame/GameManager
```

Comment: It should not be a problem to find tutorials or introductions on that topic. For example this one gives a nice overview: [http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)

Comment: What happens if the files are already in your target directory? How about if the disk becomes full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SET $source=*Your source path*
@SET $destination=*Your destination path*

@xcopy "%$source%" "%$destination%" /E /I /R /Y /Z
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Copy failed. && GOTO :EOF
@CD /D "%$destination%"

@*Start your java command*
```

Xcopy parameters used :

- /E Copy folders and subfolders, including Empty folders
- /I Assume the destination is a folder when the destination does not exist
- /R Overwrite read-only files.
- /Y Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.
- /Z Copy files in restartable mode.

More at [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)